# White screen when one activity has been closed and previous activity is being shown

Tags: xamarin.forms

I use Xamarin Forms and Dark theme. Packages for theme I installed as described here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/themes/dark/

I have simple project with two activities. First activity contains button. When I click the button, second activity is shown. I use NavigationPage. When I invoke method Navigation.PushAsync(page), I see white screen a short time and after I see my second dark activity. When I set flag 'animated' to false, I don't see that when second activity is being opened. But the same problem occurs when I press 'back' button and second activity is being closed.

Why I see white activity when second activity is being closed and first is being show ? Can I change that color ?

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest prerelease? This sounds like an issue that was resolved in 2.3.3-pre3.

Comment: You'll need to share how you are setting the theme. Themes can be applied in various ways for Android and sometimes simply setting it a different way can resolve the issue.

Comment: @samiz, I can't use 2.3.3-pre3 because Xamarin.Forms.Themes.DarkThemeResources uses Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Internals.SimpleValueTargetProvider.ctor with single parameter, but 2.3.3-pre3 provides constructor with 2 parameters and Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Dark has just one version

Answer (score 0):

Some project presets for Xamarin in Visual Studio contain default "styles.xml" file is containing some style overrides for base style.
This style name is used in configuration attribute for the application.

DarkTheme package sets controls styles via merge ResourceDictionaries in App.xaml. There is a problem. I think, these styles (in "styles.xml" and in the resource dictionary) interfere each other.

So I just delete "styles.xml", remove theme name from configuration attribute for the application and everything is working fine.